# GNU MakeFile question

Tags: gcc, makefile

I use the GCC compiler.

When compiling a program one often needs to link in a huge number of library files like .so extension to get the program to work.

Now for the C program that I am writing all the library files I need to link are inside a folder.

What should I write in my GNU Makefile if I wish to link ALL the library files in that folder to my program/executable.

Comment: You should write the same command you would use on the command line. This is not really a makefile problem. Editing tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
target.exe: target.o
     gcc -o target.exe target.o libdir/*.so
```